# How to reuse code with Dynamic hiera.yaml in several projects?

Tags: puppet

I have a single puppet master on which puppet modules reside.

I want to use the same code and single puppet master to deploy on the code on different environments for different projects. To store the data I am using hiera. The challenge is there are a few project specific data and the code is the same.

Is there a way to use the project specific file in hiera hierarchy at run time. If I am running puppet for project A it will pickup project A specific variables in hiera hierarchy and for project B it will pickup project B specific data.

By setting multiple puppet masters we can achieve this. How can we do that using a single puppet master?

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely possible! In the `hiera.yaml` file, you can set up custom hierarchies based on facts, such as:

```
---
:hierarchy:
  - "%{module_name}/%{::fqdn}"
  - "%{module_name}/%{::domain}"
  - "%{module_name}/global"
  - "global"
```

In this case, if you were to give distinct domain names to your environments (such as `dev.site`, `prod.site`, `test.site`, etc.), different hiera files would be looked up. It works with any fact that could be useful (for example, the `network` or `environment` facts).

Comment: We do this but use custom file based facts in ``/etc/facter/facts.d``

Comment: Thanks bartavelle for the response. How we can set the module_name as at run time. For example suppose module_A team is doing puppet run then how hiera find out runtime that module_A team specific hiera file is used. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Vorsprung - Are you using the custom facts on agent side or master side? I want to do it on master side. As different teams will run the puppet from console. Puppet code is same for all the teams or projects but their data may be different. I want hiera to pickup the project specific data on top in the hierarchy.

Comment: `module_name` is a special variable that is set to the name of the module being loaded, you can't set it up yourself!

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you found some differentiating factor between your groups. It could as easy as running puppet with a difference "environment" value ...